# How do you make a melee attack?

Tags: xbox-360, dead-space

How do you melee attack (*swing your hand wielding the weapon*) in Dead Space?  I know curb stomp is RB next to fallen enemy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can confirm it's the right trigger. I just checked on my Xbox 360. It's really a last-ditch sort of thing; I wouldn't suggest counting on it.

Answer (score 2):

It is the right trigger, but more importantly you need to make sure you are not also holding down the left trigger or you will fire the weapon instead of initiating a melee attack.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the right trigger is the melee attack with whatever you're holding.

Comment: In my experience, meleeing is what you do when you are pretty much already dead. You can also think of it as a "watch the cool player death scene" animation button as well.